# Search through foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one table for products in which I have many columns and I also have one column for `category_id`

`category_id` is foreign key here which refers to category table primary key

Now suppose if someone search via keyword `%category_name%` than I want list of product which have their category in foreign key

How to do that?
Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 2):

First, you join table `product` to `category` using `product.category_id` as Foreign Key.

Then you filter `category_name` (in this case I used `LIKE` and `keyword`). And last you select columns that you need:

```
SELECT product.*
FROM product 
    INNER JOIN category ON product.category_id = category.category_id
WHERE category.category_name LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Answer (score 2):

try this, it will work for you

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN category c ON p.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE c.category_name LIKE '%search%';
```

Comment: please mark it the correct answer :)